# Function to find closest value or closest sum value of elements to given number

Tags: php

I want to send an integer array and a number to function and function will give me closest element or element sum to my number.
for example: our funtion name is findclosestsum.

> findClosestSum([2, 3, 7, 14, 15], 25)  --> must give 3,7,15 because sum of this 3 element is exactly 25.

> findClosestSum([2, 3, 7, 14, 15], 15)  --> must give only 15

> findClosestSum([2, 3, 7, 14, 15], 11)  --> must give 3,7 because sum=10 and very closer to 11

here is my php code

```
function findClosestSum($array, $number) {
  $result = [];
  $minDiff = null;
  $arrayCount = count($array);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $arrayCount; $i++) {
      for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $arrayCount; $j++) {
          $sum = $array[$i] + $array[$j];
          $diff = abs($number - $sum);
          if ($sum == $number) {
              return [$array[$i], $array[$j]];
          } elseif ($minDiff === null || $diff < $minDiff) {
              $minDiff = $diff;
              $result = [$array[$i], $array[$j]];
          }
      }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

it returns 7 and 15 for findClosestSum([2, 3, 7, 14, 15], 25). where is my mistake?

Comment: There are too many unknowns in your question: eg. Is the array always ascending? can the sum skip values ie if the given value 16, could it be 2+14 as the closest total?

Comment: no array may be mixed. and sum of elements can not be bigger than given number.

Comment: and what about if there exists more than one combination that match? eg. [2,7,8,13], 15 which would I assume result in 2 winners ie: 2,13 and 7,8  - and potentially more then just 2 in larger arrays

Comment: good question. first match is enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem in a more productive and precise result, you may need to implement this with graphs.